# Values are overwrite while saving in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

i am saving the user info in the NSMutableDictionary with key "username" and then saving this Dictionary in another NSMutableDictionary with key "name" and then saving the Dictionary in the NSMutableArray. But the Problem is that whenever i save another user with different username it overwrites the values in the NSMutableArray. Below is the code which i am using

```
-(void) saveUserData:(NSString *)username
```

{
    NSLog(@"\nsaveDataBarButtonTapped \n");

```
NSLog(@"the count is %d",[[[ArraysManager sharedInstance] getTotalUserArray] count]);

NSLog(@"ArraysManager description is  %@ ",[[[ArraysManager sharedInstance] getTotalUserArray] description]);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *userArrayFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userData"]];

if (username.length != 0)
{
    [dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",username] forKey:@"username"];
    [dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf",totalValue] forKey:@"totalValue"];
    [dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf",totalPayable]  forKey:@"totalPayable"];

    [userDictionary setObject:dataDictionary  forKey:@"userDictionary"];

    [[[ArraysManager sharedInstance] getTotalUserArray] addObject:userDictionary];
    [[[ArraysManager sharedInstance] getTotalUserArray] writeToFile:userArrayFilePath atomically:NO];

    [dataDictionary removeAllObjects];
    [userDictionary removeAllObjects];

    NSLog(@"ArraysManager description is  %@ ",[[[ArraysManager sharedInstance] getTotalUserArray] description]);
}

else 
{
    UIAlertView *noNameAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Name Found" 
                                                              message:@"Please Enter the User Name" 
                                                             delegate:self 
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [noNameAlertView show];
    [noNameAlertView release];
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write:

```
 [userDictionary setObject:dataDictionary  forKey:username];
```

(Actually I don't understand why you do;

```
[[[ArraysManager sharedInstance] getTotalUserArray] addObject:userDictionary];
```

it seems like you are adding the same dictionary each time.)

Comment: i am adding the userDictionary to the NSmutableArray

Answer (score 0):

I think you save with the same key on both occasions so it access the same array, you need to change the key for different dictionaries.

EDIT:

```
[userDictionary setObject:dataDictionary  forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name%d,nameCount"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[dataDictionary removeAllObjects];
[userDictionary removeAllObjects];
```

I think both the above objects are member variables and you are reusing those member variables to add data to your array. Removing objects from dictionary will not create a new dictionary object but are getting updated in same memory location. Your array will have multiple dictionaries and sub-dictionaries but all are having 2 objects of these all at same memory location.

Instead of these member variables, use these as local variables.
Initialize them in this method and add them to array.
Later release them before end of this method.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `addObject` with the same `NSMutableDictionary` object.

Did you check the `count` property after `addObject`?

For quick fix, just `copy` the dictionary before add it to the array.

[[[ArraysManager sharedInstance] getTotalUserArray] addObject:[[userDictionary copy] autorelease];

(`autorelease` for non-ARC configuration)